# want to write code for popup window from my given code

Tags: php

i have a simple website which is written by php code. i have a detect button on my page and given below code is writen for this function but my problem is i need a popup window when the detect link is clicked. i have tired to set a code in my created code but i am not able .kindly please help me solve this problem.

```
<?php 
/*echo "permessi".$permessi;
echo "<br>id".$id_nome;*/

if($action=='canc'){?>
    <h1>are you sure want to delect the course?</h1>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="canc1" style="float: left; margin-left:25px;">
<input type="hidden" name="idcorsocanc" value="<?=$canc_id?>">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="Si,cancella" class="puls_invia">
</form>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="canc2" style="float: left; margin-left:25px;">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="NO" class="puls_invia">
</form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: So you want to open a pop up on click of a button??

Comment: yes i would like to add a popup window on click from my delect button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
function open_win()
{
window.open("URL HERE")
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">
```

Comment: hi sankalp,thanks for reply but the problem is i ma not very expert in php and this code is written on my index.php page. and from your code how i conect with my given code? or i just have to write this code in my index.php page?

Comment: You may write this in index.php page. The button i showed here is actually your delele button. give i a try and tell

Comment: hi, i am realy sorry i get confused .and it is not working on my index.php page? cause as you saw my given code after that in my index.php page i add your code with my url link but it is not working.can u kindly tell me where i did mistake .

Comment: hi i try to write my whole code but in comment it dont goes and from my post i cant asnwer.what i ahve to do tell me plz. i explain to you.as you saw my 1st code in my question i did not chnage any thing form my previous code and after that just i put your given code and just i put my own url address but it does not works.

Comment: till now i am waiting for a solution for my problem.is their anybody who can help me. thanks

Comment: ok i want to clear my question again, hope their is someone who can help me for solve this problem. i have writen php code for my website and my need is-i have a table where i put title of my course .end and start date of course and modify the course and delect the course all the thigns is in a raw.my problem is when student will click the delect link their should be one popup window they can visit but now if i click the window is ups in the same page i mean "are you wnat to delect" this permission i need a pop up window not in the same page i want to see . hope now my question is clear.

Comment: hi to all again i want to ask u about my problem.till now there is no solution i had.there is no one who can solve my problem?? waiting for a good and quick response. is my question is not clear kindly ask me. i will write details again....